# C# listview subitems not showing up

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm a beginner in C# and I am trying to create a simple view, where I have data listed into two separate columns in a `ListView`. I have created the columns, and added subItems to two different `ListViewItems`. However, when compiling only the main item shows up, an no `SubItems` are present.

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Client Code");
listView1.Columns.Add("Client Name");


 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Client Code");


        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("Client Name");

        listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {item, item2});

        foreach(string clientCode in clientCodes) 
        //clientCode is a list of Strings initialized earlier in the code
        {

        listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add(code);

        }
```

I have also tried the following, with no success:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Client Code");

        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("Client Name");

foreach(string clientCode in clientCodes) 
        //clientCode is a list of Strings initialized earlier in the code
        {

        item.SubItems.Add(code);

        }

        listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {item, item2});
```

Simply adding

```
item.SubItems.Add("test");
```

or

```
listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add("test");
```

also has no effect.

The output of the code above is two columns, one with "Client Code" and one with "Client Name" but no additional data.

What am I doing wrong, why isn't any of the data showing up in the columns?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to set the **View** property of **ListView** as **View.Details** before adding items to display the items as shown below.

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("Client Code");
listView1.Columns.Add("Client Name");
```

Comment: Thank you! Fixed everything. Just out of curiosity, what exactly does setting it to View.Details do?

Comment: It sets the display to: "Each item appears on a separate line with further information about each item arranged in columns. The left-most column contains a small icon and label, and subsequent columns contain sub items as specified by the application. A column displays a header which can display a caption for the column. The user can resize each column at run time."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.view?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_View_Details

Comment: The View property of ListView specifies how to display its items,  where setting View.Details will display all the details of the ListView such as subitems..